How to viewport rotate around model's nose instead of model's center?
In Preferences, I have ticked Navigation > Orbit & Pan > Orbit Around Selection. It orbits around my humanoid model, but the rotation point is somewhere in the middle of the mesh, in the hips. How can I change the rotation point to be the model's nose?
When it rotates around the hips, if I'm working on the face, the model sometimes rotates the head towards me and away from me really fast. I would like to change the rotation point to the nose or center of the head, it would make it easier to control.
I have tried setting the object's origin to the model's nose, then select Individual Origins in Transform Pivot Point drop down, but did not help.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions !!

What you say happens in Object mode, in Edit mode though the rotation happens around the selected face(s)

Thanks -- I was hoping it had it in Object Mode because I use that the most to look at the finished work. Oh well, guess I have to zoom out first.

Oof!! Right in the manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/navigation.html#orbit
"Clicking a point with Alt-MMB will make it the point of interest: it becomes the central point which the view orbits around."
This gets me closer to what I wanted, including in Object Mode. If I Alt-MMB on the model's nose, it becomes much easier to control the orbiting.

Adjusting the preferred pivot point for orbiting can be done by going into Edit Mode then selecting the mesh and pressing the Numpad Del or Numpad Period key. This function is often called "Frame Selected" or "Zoom to Selection."
